# What are the correct file permission settings for magento 2.2 on a single-user production environment?

Tags: magento2, file-permissions, production-mode

I am setting up a Magento 2.2.5 instance on a production environment (single-user / shared hosting). When it comes to file permissions, I found two documentation pages:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

When following the instructions for a shared hosting environment at the first link, everything is fine. But, I assumed I had to follow the instructions at the second link as well since I am configuring a production environment. As soon as I run the command to "Make code files and directories read-only", I get an error like this: `Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception`, because cache_dir `var/page_cache` is not writable.

This seems logical since the command made `var` read-only.

So, is the documentation wrong? Or should I somehow only follow the documentation at the first link, not the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an explanation of what each folder does in var: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html

It makes sense that view_preprocessed folder is made read only after the files have been generated. It also makes sense that the generated folder is write only after its generated, but some things can't be read only in var (example: logs).

Looks like a devdocs mistake with the command not doing what the best practice describes above it.

Comment: I am on a single-user environment (edited question to add that information). Both owner and group of all files are set to this user. My question is, why does the documentation state to make `var` read-only, while Magento does seem to need to write to it?

Comment: I see what you mean. The devdocs say that for production mode for single user, that var/view_preprocessed should not have write permissions, but the command they offer removes write access to var.

Comment: Var cannot be read only for the user running hosting software. Example: log writing. Parts of it maybe, and if logs are managed by a different system maybe, but not out of the box.

Comment: Here's an explanation of what each folder does in var: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html . It makes sense that view_preprocessed made read only after the files have been generated, also makes sense that the generated folder is write only after its generated, but some things can't be read only in var. Looks like a devdocs mistake with the command not doing what the best practice describes above it.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you could put that in a separate answer so I can accept that?